# unable to get Facebook Share success callback

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I make a url like this to share video on facebook.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://streetinvasion.com/test/&t=Faulkner+-+Smuggle+your+media" class="smgl_vid">share this</a>
```

Its working but i need to get success callback to track whether some one really share it or not. 
Please give me explain or provide me complete process.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The facebook share button (or the share url) is deprecated, you can read it in the docs:

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/)

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

(reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

Use the like button instead of the share and then register to the *edge.create* event using [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/), something like:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```